# Problemas com select em múltiplas tabelas

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, select

Estou tentando fazer a conversão de um select do sql server para o Dapper, como ele estava muito grande, estou querendo deixar mais enxuto e legível...
Porém esta aparecendo erro em algumas trechos

```
SELECT
    email.assunto [Assunto],
    disp.cod_disparador [DisparadorID],
    p.Desc_Pessoa [DescricaoPessoa],
    ee.cod_Email_Auto_Config_Disparador_Email_Empresa [EmailDisparadorConfigID]
FROM 
    CL2_Empresa emp,
    CL2_Email_Auto_Config_Disparador_Email email,
    CL2_Email_Auto_Config_Disparador disp,
    CL2_Pessoa p,
    CL2_Email_Auto_Config_Disparador_Email_Empresa ee 
INNER JOIN  CL2_Email_Auto_Config_Disparador_Email_Empresa 
    ON CL2_Empresa.Cod_Empresa = ee.Cod_Empresa 
INNER JOIN  CL2_Pessoa 
    ON CL2_Empresa.Cod_Pessoa = CL2_Pessoa.Cod_Pessoa 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN    CL2_Email_Auto_Config_Disparador 
INNER JOIN  CL2_Email_Auto_Config_Disparador_Email 
    ON CL2_Email_Auto_Config_Disparador.cod_disparador = CL2_Email_Auto_Config_Disparador_Email.cod_disparador 
    ON ee.cod_disparador_email = CL2_Email_Auto_Config_Disparador_Email.cod_disparador_email
WHERE 
    (disp.cod_disparador = 2)
```

Mas nessas duas linhas, aparece a mensagem de erro:

> (the mult-part identifier "nome do campo" could not be bound)

```
CL2_Email_Auto_Config_Disparador_Email_Empresa ON CL2_Empresa.Cod_Empresa = ee.Cod_Empresa INNER JOIN CL2_Pessoa ON CL2_Empresa.Cod_Pessoa = CL2_Pessoa.Cod_Pessoa RIGHT OUTER JOIN
```

Comment: Você tem um `inner join` para uma tabela que ja foi listada. então ele se perdeu em qual deve usar, a com alias ou a sem.

Comment: seu select ta muito bagunçado, você começa de uma forma e depois começa a usar inner join.. user uma coisa ou outra.

Comment: @GOKUSSJGod, realmente... Alterei o select e ele me trouxe os mesmos campos e ainda ficou mais limpo visivelmente... :)

Comment: já corrigiu, você pode posta como corrigiu ou deletar a pergunta.

Comment: SELECT email.assunto [Assunto], disp.cod_disparador [DisparadorID],    p.Desc_Pessoa [DescricaoPessoa],                   ee.cod_Email_Auto_Config_Disparador_Email_Empresa [EmailDisparadorConfigID]
FROM   CL2_Email_Auto_Config_Disparador_Email email, CL2_Email_Auto_Config_Disparador disp, CL2_Pessoa p, CL2_Email_Auto_Config_Disparador_Email_Empresa ee  
WHERE (disp.cod_disparador = 2)

Só ficou sem formatação hehehe
Obrigado @GuilhermeLautert e @GOKUSSJGod!!!

Comment: @Mfilho_19 não poste como um comentário, poste como uma resposta e aceite ela.

Comment: @Genos Não entendi, poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: @Mfilho_19 Ao invés de postar a solução como um comentário, use o botão abaixo(acredito que para o dono da pergunta seja algo como 'Responder minha pergunta') para postar a solução como uma resposta oficial. Depois aceite essa resposta.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT email.assunto [Assunto]
      ,disp.cod_disparador [DisparadorID]
      ,p.Desc_Pessoa [DescricaoPessoa]
      ,ee.cod_Email_Auto_Config_Disparador_Email_Empresa [EmailDisparadorConfigID] 
FROM  CL2_Email_Auto_Config_Disparador_Email email 
     ,CL2_Email_Auto_Config_Disparador disp
     ,CL2_Pessoa p 
     ,CL2_Email_Auto_Config_Disparador_Email_Empresa ee 
WHERE (disp.cod_disparador = 2)
```